# empty jockey install proprietory nvidia after bumblebee on 13.04

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, bumblebee, jockey

I am trying to install the proprietory Nvidia drivers on my Asus UX32VD (GT620M) running 13.04.

Since the additional drivers (Jockey) tab was empty I followed the advice from a similar question here to install Bumblebee. Unfortunately the Jockey tab is still empty (as in, my card does not show up).

My question is twofold

1. how do I get the Nvidia drivers to show up in the additional drivers tab?
2. after having installed Bumblebee, which is the way to install Nvidia drivers? (as the Bumblebee site mentions something on specific packages)

Upon request:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1507
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1507
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at cfe08000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1507
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do I fix the additional drivers tab?

You don't *fix* the additional drivers tab. It is showing what is supposed to show: nothing. Bumblebee is a free driver, jockey will show you proprietary. If Bumblebee drivers works fine using nouveau drivers, why try to install the proprietary?

> after having installed Bumblebee, which is the way to install Nvidia drivers? (as the Bumblebee site mentions something on specific packages)

The only packages you have to install are:

```
bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

**None of them are the proprietary Nvidia drivers**. Nowhere in the [Bumblebee site](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html) nor the [Ubuntu installation guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) mentions having to install proprietary drivers. If you follow the guide and install bumblebee as intended, no problems will arise:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

After that, you only need to reboot and use `optirun` when an application that has heavy GPU demands require (ie. a game, firefox, etc.).

Comment: thank you for your answers. I think I should have been more clear in my question. I have installed Bumblebee, but I also want to install the proprietory drivers, how do I do that?

Comment: I have edited my question the be more specific